# Magento 2 setCollection in phtml?

Tags: magento2, product-collection

In Magento 1.9, If I want to call another phtml file in currenct phtml, I could use something as below.

```
            /** @var Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List $productsBlock */
            $productsBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list');
            $productsBlock->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/summary.phtml');
            $productsBlock->setCollection($itemsByCategory[$_category->getId()]);
            echo $productsBlock->toHtml();
```

I wonder if `setCollection` is working in Magento 2?

Because When I use the same code in Magento 2, I got an error,

```
Call to a member function count() on null
```

on the function `$_productCollection->count()` in the summary.pthml that I'm including.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `summery.phtml` is your custom file, then this should work. I mean it wont work on `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml` but it will work if you are doing it in your custom phtml file you just need to pass your collection and use core template block like this:

```
<?php
if($itemsByCategory[$_category->getId()]){
echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
            ->setCollection($itemsByCategory[$_category->getId()])
            ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/list/summary.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
}
else{
    echo "Collection is not even loaded";
}
```

And can get it in your in your custom phtml `summery.phtml`

```
<?php
$_productCollection = $this->getColletion();
if($_productCollection){
    echo $_productCollection->count();
}
else{
    echo "Unable to get collection";
}
```

Note: I have added some checks so that you can see if collection is loaded properly.

Comment: Thanks, When I use $this->getCollection() in summary.php,the the error is gone, and everyhtings working as suppose. 

The problem was because I used $this->getLoadedProductCollection() in summary.php.

Now I have a new problem. If I use $this->getCollection, then I can not access this summary.phtml directly. It's working only If I call it from another pthml. 

And $this->getLoadedProductCollection(); works fine when directly access the summary.pthml.  How can I get it to working both when including from another phtml and direct access?

Comment: I got it fixed by checking whether $this->getLoadedProductCollection exist. if not then using $this->getCollection, in the summary.phtml. Thanks for the help

Comment: Good to hear that you have resolved it. +1 for answer acceptance :)